# How to fetch comma separated value in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have  table callled student.I want name of student whose isactive is 1 and who have subjectcode 1.Like does not work here.It gave name of employee who have subject code 11 or 12 also.

```
id  name    Isactive    subjectcode
1   Shilpa  1           1,2,3
2   Manasi  1           11
3   kamal   1           12,3
4   Hans    0           1,2
5   Rupali  1          1,11,12
```

Comment: Normalisation. Please do it.

Comment: Did my solution below work for you? It should be suitable even for a large amount of records. However, as Mitch mentioned - normalisation would be the ideal way to go.

Comment: Consider selecting an answer from the list of replies you got below @Jui Test...

Answer (score 0):

First create this function

```
create function [dbo].[fnSplitString]
(
    @string nvarchar(max)
    ,@delimiter char(1) = ','
)
returns @t table(string nvarchar(max))
as 
begin 
    declare @pos int
    declare @piece varchar(500)

    if right(rtrim(@string),1) <> @delimiter
     set @string = @string  + @delimiter

    set @pos =  patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @string)
    while @pos <> 0 
    begin
     set @piece = left(@string, @pos - 1)

    insert  @t
    select  @piece

     set @string = stuff(@string, 1, @pos,'')
     set @pos =  patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @string)
    end 
    return
end
```

Then run this

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (id Int,name Varchar(50),isactive Bit, subjectCode Varchar(200))

INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 1 ,  'Shilpa' , 1    ,       '1,2,3'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 2 , 'Manasi' , 1    ,       '11'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 3 ,  'kamal',   1    ,       '12,3'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 4 ,  'Hans' ,   0     ,      '1,2'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 5 ,  'Rupali' , 1    ,      '1,11,12'

    SELECT * FROM @result WHERE isactive=1 AND 
(11 IN(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString](subjectCode,',')) 
OR 12 in
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString](subjectCode,',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tried below sql query

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (id Int,name Varchar(50),isactive Bit, subjectCode Varchar(200))

INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 1 ,  'Shilpa' , 1    ,       '1,2,3'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 2 , 'Manasi' , 1    ,       '11'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 3 ,  'kamal',   1    ,       '12,3'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 4 ,  'Hans' ,   0     ,      '1,2'
INSERT INTO @result 
SELECT 5 ,  'Rupali' , 1    ,      '1,11,12'

select * from @result where Isactive = 1 and (','+ subjectcode + ',') like '%,' + '1' + ',%'
```

Comment: Therae are lot of record

Answer (score 0):

please use following condition instead of like

```
where CHARINDEX('1,',subjectcode) > 0 or CHARINDEX(',1',subjectcode) > 0
```

This will work.